# C Program char array error

Tags: c, arrays, timer, char

I am trying to understand how the size of the char array "buf" is affecting my interval timer setup.  Everything works fine as long as I allocate the buffer to the size of the strings being combined "Good" and "Day".

When I set the size of "buf" to something larger, 100 in my example I get a failure on my settimer function.

Does anyone see a connection between the char arrary size and the settimer function?

If I need to provide more detail let me know and I will post it.

Compiled with arm-linux-gcc. No compilation errors.

**Fails**

```
#define INTERVAL 30

void interval(void);

void exit_func (int i)
{
    signal(SIGINT,exit_func);
    printf("\nExiting!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int main(){

    char buf[100] = "";
    char *cur = buf, * const end = buf + sizeof buf;

    cur += snprintf(cur, end-cur, "%s", "Good");
    if (cur < end) {
        cur += snprintf(cur, end-cur, "%s", "Day");
     }


     //timer code
     struct itimerval it_val;  /* for setting itimer */

    if (signal(SIGALRM, (void (*)(int)) interval) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
        exit(1);
    }

    it_val.it_value.tv_sec =    INTERVAL; 
    it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;

    if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1) {
       perror("error calling setitimer()");
       exit(1);
    }

}

void interval(void) {
    //execute interval code
}
```

Fails upon execution with error: error calling setitimer(): Invalid argument

**Works**

```
#define INTERVAL 30

void interval(void);

void exit_func (int i)
{
    signal(SIGINT,exit_func);
    printf("\nExiting!\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(){

    char buf[7] = "";
    char *cur = buf, * const end = buf + sizeof buf;

    cur += snprintf(cur, end-cur, "%s", "Good");
    if (cur < end) {
        cur += snprintf(cur, end-cur, "%s", "Day");
     }


     //timer code
     struct itimerval it_val;  /* for setting itimer */

    if (signal(SIGALRM, (void (*)(int)) interval) == SIG_ERR) {
        perror("Unable to catch SIGALRM");
        exit(1);
    }

    it_val.it_value.tv_sec =    INTERVAL; 
    it_val.it_interval = it_val.it_value;

    if (setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it_val, NULL) == -1) {
       perror("error calling setitimer()");
       exit(1);
    }

}

void interval(void) {
    //execute interval code
}
```

Comment: Without executing the code I would say that the problem is UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR. Because concatenating strings in c is difficult and most beginners do it wrong, but I have never seen a method worse than this.

Comment: The question lacks a definition of `INTERVAL`.

Comment: INTERVAL definition added.

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Yet the code seems legit, especially assuming the resulting string is not used anywhere...

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Can you point to what you consider to be a superior method for concatenating strings in C?  I would really like to know the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: `strcat` and friends, obviously...

Comment: @lurker You are right that the size of 7 is too small to hold the string but it does not cause it to fail.  I tested different array sizes and it works up until 32; at buf[32] and above it fails.

Comment: Is this the *full* code? When you say "fail" - how it fails? Is this running on some conventional desktop or some embedded system? (I am asking it because there could be some stack limitation)

Comment: *Update*: Now I see it is for some ARM machine. Check you stack limitation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am fairly new to embedded ARM systems but I ran the command $ulimit -a and found the ARM linux stack size info as shown here: stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192

Comment: Should be fine.. And for my other questions?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I did not have the exit function nor the interval function; now added.  The fail is when the code is executed there is an error message in regards to the settimer. The error displays: "error calling setitimer(): Invalid argument".  Which only happens when buf array size is 32 or greater.

Comment: So how does it fail? And the body of `interval` might help.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The fail is when the code is executed there is an error message in regards to the settimer. The error displays: "error calling setitimer(): Invalid argument". Which only happens when buf array size is 32 or greater.   The body of interval is empty in the current code I am using to evaluate this error.

Comment: OK.. try setting `tv_usec`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Wow! That seems to have worked.  Why would that fix it?

Comment: `man setitimer` and look when `EINVAL` is happening

Comment: @EugeneSh. Many Thanks!

Comment: @user3258873 It really depends. But this method is very creative and I didn't say it was wrong, but it has the potential to be if you are not very, very careful.